# Spring Security Session Timeout - Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My Spring security works well but after some afk time I start getting tons of exceptions when the user goes to the pages.

I noticed that `session and principal is null` that's why I get error 500.

How do I redirect the user that to the login again?

Or I can simply remove the session timeout (i dont really need it)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true)
@ComponentScan("pt.impactzero.atp")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    private LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("Administrator" , "Member")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard",true)
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall() {
        DefaultHttpFirewall firewall = new DefaultHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        return firewall;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver(){
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    //Online users
    @Bean
    public ActiveUsers activeUsers(){
        return new ActiveUsers();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want disable session, you can:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // disable session
    http.sessionManagement().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("Administrator" , "Member")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard",true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```

if you want redirect user to login page, you can try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // redirect user to login page
    http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("http://your.login.page").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("Administrator" , "Member")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard",true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}
```